# Magento 2 : How to remove $this->messageManager->addError() message from php file

Tags: magento2

I have already added the error message using

```
$this->messageManager->addError('Error');
```

after some condition we need to remove that particular error message from php file not JS.

Thanks

Comment: explain briefly

Comment: When click reset password link from mail then showing old error message, but other page working fine